# Getting Voronoi diagram info from C++ interface of the Qhull library

Tags: c++, voronoi, qhull

I'm using the Qhull library with the C++ interface. Basically what I've been trying to do is get Voronoi diagram info out of it, such as Voronoi regions, vertices, facets, etc. However, the interface seems to be incomplete. Right now I can only access to the Voronoi vertices (actually called facets in the library). I was wondering if someone has been successfull in getting regions and facets/ridges with this library.

For the moment I am able to access the info reading from  `qhullMessage()` , which produces strings with the info I need, but this method is quite slow (parsing/casting). 
I hope someone can help me with this, thanks.